# Stories about Prophet Seth

Tags: hadith, history, authenticity, prophets

Are there any authentic narrations about Prophet Sheeth (AS) in any authentic books or other books of hadith? How authentic are the stories told about him?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is prophet sheeth mentioned in quran or he is mentioned in hadith](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/64596/is-prophet-sheeth-mentioned-in-quran-or-he-is-mentioned-in-hadith)

Answer (score -1):

Assalamualaikum,
In short, we don't have anything definite on him. Nothing in Quran by name, I think maybe a mention or two in weak hadith. Ibn kathir got a lot of his information from christian/jewish sources, which was okay as the wikipedia of its time, but as a matter of theology we can't affirm or deny anything related to Seth, maybe he was, maybe he wasn't.

Answer (score -1):

A short report is written in Genesis 4:26-5:8

The recite from the Torah can be considered «authentic», as the Torah in general is among the authentic books confirmed in the Quran, and in particular it is written

Al-Ma'ida 5:27

> And relate to them the true story of Adam's two sons: when they
> offered an offering, and it was accepted from one of them, but it was
> not accepted from the other. He Said, “I will kill you.” He Said, “God
> accepts only from the righteous.”

which is the preceeding [passage](https://biblehub.com/nasb_/genesis/4.htm) about Kain and Abel in the book. «Relate to them the true story» means to tell the whole story (which is only mentioned but not cited in full length) and consider it as a truth.