# Is prophet sheeth mentioned in quran or he is mentioned in hadith

Tags: quran, prophets

There are many scholar that say sheeth(A.S)was a prophet, so is he mentioned in quran.
And can you give verse for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seth (شيث) is not mentioned by name in the Quran. He is mentioned in a hadith recorded by Ibn Hibban, whose authenticity has been criticized by some. There is scarce evidence about him.

> أنزل على شيث خمسون صحيفة
>
> fifty pages were sent down to Sheeth
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Ibn Hibban](https://shamela.ws/book/537/949)</sup>

Comment: Maybe this would answer https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/63969/stories-about-prophet-seth

Comment: What is the earliest Hadith book in which he is mentioned? please and thanks

Comment: The link to the hadith appears to lead to a missing page

Answer (score 0):

The name of Seth is not mentioned in the Qur'an, but in Islamic hadiths and narrations, the name of Seth is mentioned as one of the prophets in Islam.